# Comparing 2 maps Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

Given 2 maps:

```
Map<String, Integer> m1;
Map<String, Integer> m2;
```

I was wondering if there is a fast method with Java stream to implement a method returning `true` or `false` if the maps are equals i.e. have the same size, the same keyset and the same value for each key.

```
public <K> boolean compareMaps(Map<String, K> m1, Map<String, K> m2);
```

Comment: Huh... `return m1.equals(m2);`?

Comment: @assylias: but this isn’t a *Stream solution*. I’m quite sure, we can find an elegant twenty-liner (but still being a single statement—that’s important) using the Stream API…

Comment: ok guys... approved ...thanks.